Can/should we tell people that AI cut and paste answers are not welcome?
We now commonly see new users pop up and post a string of nonsense, AI-generated answers to a bunch of questions, before their accounts are eventually banned.
In order to counteract this, could we have a message on the new user registration page explaining that this behavior is not welcome? Should we do that?
EDIT: I agree with the comments that we should also think about saying AI-generated questions are especially discouraged.

There are also other options where this information could be placed.  One option would be to include this in the banner, which was discussed here: Should there be a banner with some basic info about MO in the right sidebar? MO has FAQ here on meta - although looking at some of them suggests they are no longer maintained. And possibly this could be also included in the help center.

It is probably worth reminding that it is possible to post on MO also without registration. Registration to ask questions was discussed but rejected: Should MathOverflow require registration to ask a question? I do not recall any discussion about registration to answer questions here on MO.

Less frequent, but in some ways more insidious, are instances of questions that are being generated by prompting LLMs and then posting the results with no indications that the poster's brain has been involved.

@SamHopkins It does make me wish there was an equivalent of the anti-graffiti wall from The Naked Gun...

I think that AI generated answers can be OK as long as it is stated, that it is an AI generated answer and that the user clearly states what the user has done to verify its correctness. Why someone would post an AI generated question is beyond me, well maybe it is a good way for non-native English speakers to improve the grammar. Maybe I should try it.

I wouldn't trust an LLM to correctly translate mathematical prose. One should be able to check that the software hasn't hallucinated and made up nonsense.

Note that our Help Center currently states that AI-generated content is allowed on MO, as long as you disclose which AI you used to generate it.

Are you sure that the users who post AI-generated answers and questions are human themselves? I thought that some robots create new users and post answers in order to learn math.

Stack Exchange sites can request a banner reminding users that AI generated answers are not allowed.
